# How to roslaunch a rostopic echo to text file

Tags: roslaunch, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to do something like this from a launch file:

```
rostopic echo -p /mytopic > outputfile.txt
```

I wrote this in the launch file:

```
<node name="pioneer3at" pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic" output="screen" args="echo -p /tf_P3AT > outputfile.txt">
```

However, it doesn't work and I received an error like this:

```
Usage: rostopic echo [options] /topic

rostopic: error: you may only specify one input topic
[pioneer3at-1] process has died [pid 3482, exit code 2, cmd /opt/ros/indigo/lib/rostopic/rostopic echo -p /tf_P3AT > outputfile.txt __name:=pioneer3at __log:=/home/danieladmin/.ros/log/873003e4c-9bb4-11e4-8a96-08002709c13/pioneer3at-1*.log].
```

log file: /home/user/.ros/log/edae921e-f970-11e2-be82-14feb5b7467c/output_topic1-8*.log

Similar to as listed in this question:

http://answers.ros.org/question/70009/rostopic-echo-with-launch-file/

If I delete the part that saves to file, specifically:

```
> outputfile.txt
```

I am able to print the args to screen. Does xml have another command that I may use for > to save to file?
Else do I need some other work around?

Also, I prefer not to use a bag file in this instance for my workflow.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200922/how-to-roslaunch-a-rostopic-echo-to-text-file./) by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2015-01-14

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Andromeda](https://answers.ros.org/users/19675/andromeda/) on 2015-01-14**:
Why the option parameter `-p` ? I cannot find it in the `echo` man page

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-01-14**:
-p Displays messages in a matlab/octave-friendly plotting format. Cannot be used with -c. Check here: [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/rostopic)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not possible to do it like this because `> outputfile.txt` is a bash / shell specific operation. Unlike `-p /tf_P3AT` which are passed to the executable as `argv` to its `main( int argc, char** argv )` function the part  `> outputfile.txt` is handled by the shell itself. Therefore if used in a launch file roslaunch would have to handle it, which it is not able to.

So you need another solution. Maybe you can ad the node without  `> outputfile.txt`  and set output attribute to log.
http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node#Attributes
Then you should find a log somewhere in `$ROS_HOME/log`, which defaults to $HOME/.ros/log. However, I am not sure how/if you can specifiy the log name. Maybe run `rosclean purge` to remove previous log files  so it'll be easier to find the log file of you node....

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2015-01-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-01-14**:
Another possible solution would be to write a bash script that calls `rostopic` with the redirection `>`. Then make this script executable and ensure it has a hash-bang. Then you should be able to run this script using a standard `<node>` tag.

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-01-14**:\

- I will try your solution @jarvisschultz, then re-post my solution.
- Writing to a log file works, but I could not specify another log name, unless I edit the default of `$ROS_HOME/log`. Also, the log file did not store my header or timestamp. Do I need to call this data in my launch file??

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-01-15**:
Here is my bash script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
"true" ; exec /usr/bin/env sbcl --script "$0" "$@"
rostopic echo -p /tf_P3AT > test.txt
```

I receive: Unhandled UNBOUND-VARIABLE in thread #<SB-THREAD:THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {1002A8C073}>: The variable ROSTOPIC is unbound. And a backtrace.

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-01-15**:
That seems like an error in the way your script is running sbcl (I'm not sure what is wrong). AFAIK, there is nothing wrong with my suggestion. I just tested it, and it worked fine. My script only contained the `rostopic` part, and it had its own node tag in my launch file.

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-01-15**:
So I changed the bash script as you suggested to:

```
#! /usr/bin/env sh
rostopic echo -p /tf_P3AT > test.txt
```

It saves to /.ros/log. Do you know of a way to save to a specified folder? Also, I lose my header and timestamp in the log file. Thanks.

**Comment by [Orso](https://answers.ros.org/users/19900/orso/) on 2015-01-15**:
Changed my bash script to:

```
rostopic echo -p /tf_P3AT > /home/danieladmin/test.txt
```

This saves to home with timestamp and header. Launched with the following launch file:

```
<node pkg="pioneer3at" name="foo" type="SensorLaunchBash" />
```

Thanks @jarvisschultz. Why did I not need a hash-bang?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2015-01-15**:
You could (and probably should) have the hash-bang. If it's not there, many shells will guess that the file is a script and run it with the same shell. For your situation, this happened to work, but likely wouldn't always work. http://stackoverflow.com/a/12296783/1082525

**Comment by [flurin4](https://answers.ros.org/users/32403/flurin4/) on 2018-01-23**:
@Orso this is great!
In order to change the name of the test.txt file, I created another python script that is run once my launch file ends.
My script looks like [this](https://pastebin.com/MetzDgeX).
Call it with:

```
roslaunch package file.launch && rename_log.py
```